# creating and iterating through linked list class using a for loop

Tags: c++, class

I can not iterate through a linked list using for loop,why is that??

```
int main(){
    Node *temp=new Node();
    temp->data=3;
    Node *ans = temp;
    for(int i=1;i<10;i++){
        temp = temp->next;
        temp->data=i;
    }
    print(ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you created only one node and trying to iterate ten nodes? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you forgot to create a new Node in your loop. Indeed, `temp->next` doesn't point to anything if you didn't implicitely create a Node for it.

```
int main() {
    Node* temp = new Node();
    temp->data = 3;
    Node* ans = temp;
    for(int i=1; i<10; i++) {
        temp->next = new Node(); // Missing line
        temp = temp->next;
        temp->data = i;
    }
    print(ans);
    return 0;
}
```